# potential energy of a segment of an ideal chain under external force

Tags: torque, partition-function

I want to construct the partition function of an [ideal chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_chain) under applied external force. Let's say we apply force to both ends (with opposite sign) acting in z-direction and a segment of the ideal chain encloses an angle of $\theta$ with the z-axis:

[image: ideal chain under external force]

Now my question is, what is the potential energy of one segment of the chain depending on $f$ and $\theta$. Somehow I can not answer that question although it seems quite simple. Working with $E_{segment}=-bf\cos(\theta)$, I come to the correct result for the partition function. But I struggle explaining that energy term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you apply this force, it will be transmitted to every joint, so each segment will behave as under a field making them turn.

A way to see this is imagine only one segment tied to a fixed point: when you apply a force to the free end, what do you think the reaction force is in the fixed point? The difference now is that since each point joining two segments is free to move, and this reaction comes from acting on the next segment, which reacts to the pull with a force in the same direction and strength as the original force.

This is a case analogous to setting a magnetic field and now every segment of the chain is a magnet: when the field is activated they are all made to turn, and their interaction term with the field is similar.

The only thing to be bared in mind is that their movements are coupled, so not all angles are independent.